# Transactional annotation different behavior

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactional

I just saw two different projects.

In one of them whenever you tried to persist/save an entity from a method with no `@Transactional` annotation there was an exception that said: `No session found`

On the other

Even though no `@Transactional` annotation exists the `save` method allows saving.

PS - One project uses Spring + Hibernate (with `session not found` exception), the other uses Spring + JPA + Spring Data repositories (allows saving with no transactional annotation)

Any ideas why the differences? What's the best practice?

Comment: Are you sure that there wasn't an `@Transactional` method somewhere on the call stack of the second project? It's advice that gets wrapped around a method call, so persistence method doesn't have to have the annotation itself if it's only called from other methods that have the advice.

Comment: pretty sure, ill double check

Comment: Have you checked if there is a @Transactinal annotation at the class? If a class is annotated transactional, this affects all methods from that class.

Comment: Or maybe transactions via AOP?

Comment: Maybe in the JPA project the transactions are declared in the spring context. Search for txManager in the context (e.g. JpaTransactionManager) and track it's usage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because, as [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#transactions) of Spring Data JPA indicates

> CRUD methods on repository instances are transactional by default. For reading operations the transaction configuration readOnly flag is set to true, all others are configured with a plain @Transactional so that default transaction configuration applies. For details see JavaDoc of Repository.